# Get computers name with specific Security ID from EventViewer

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory

Need help building a powershell script that will provide me information from EventViewer for each computer.
This command provide me the full list of my computers in AD

```
Get-ADComputer -SearchBase ‘DC=test,DC=test’ -Filter * | Select-Object Name
```

And this command provide me the specific Security ID that i'm searching for(for example 4688).

```
(Get-ADComputer -SearchBase ‘DC=test,DC=test’ -Filter *).Name | Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 4688
```

Now i need to build a script of those commands, first i'm getting all the hosts from my AD, then i need to search each computer and get a list with all the computers(names) that there is a Security ID (for example 4688), and export it.Please help, Thanks.

Comment: What is the goal here? Do you need the actual event details, or are you just trying to make sure that Process Creation events are being logged according to the audit policy on the machines?

Comment: The goal is that the script will run thru GPO everyday on all the VM's that in my Domain and search for Security ID for example 4688, and will export me the names of the VM's and time when this action were taken and by who(what user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.
Script that will do the following steps:
**1.** Export all Domain computers name to the file called "ADcomputerlist.csv"
**2.** Import this file "ADcomputerlist.csv"
**3.** Search in each computer name for the past 30 days for the Security Log, InstanceID 1102.
**4.** Export the result to the file Result_Log_objects.csv with a specific date when file created.
**4.1.** Inside the file "Result_Log_objects.csv" i will find:
Name of the computers that this LogEvent exist
By who this action were taken ( for example Log Clearing )
And when this action were taken.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property * | Select-Object Name | Export-CSV C:\ADcomputerslist.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
$date = Get-Date -format "dd-MMM-yyyy"
$CurrentDate=Get-Date
$startdate=$CurrentDate.adddays(-30)
$Computers = Import-Csv -Path C:\ADcomputerslist.csv |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After $startdate -InstanceId 1102 -ComputerName $_.Name -Newest 1
        } |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\Result_Log_objects_$date.csv -NoTypeInformation
```